# Parse SDK and Swift 1.2: Can´t subclass PFUser

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Before updating to Swift 1.2 subclassing PFUser worked just fine, now I can´t make it work.

My custom PFUser-class:

```
public class CustomUser: PFUser, PFSubclassing {

    @NSManaged var fullName : String!
    @NSManaged var phone : String!

    public override class func initialize(){
        self.registerSubclass()
    }

}
```

When I use this class in my code the method calls still goes to the PFUser class:

> reason: '-[PFUser fullName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x17018fbe0'

This behavior started with Swift 1.2. I´ve updated the Parse SDK to the lastest version as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just been through this. The change in behaviour is a huge pain. You need to register your subclasses before you set your Parse app ID (typically in your application delegate).

So, in your app delegate...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
  CustomUser.registerSubclass()
  Parse.setApplicationId("XXX", clientKey: "YYY")
  ......
  return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Did you do this for all your sub-classes? My other ones seems to work without it, but I´ll do it anyway.

Comment: I did this for all of mine - better safe than sorry. Not sure if it's required.

Comment: I did this only for PFUser subclass. For all other subclasses I followed `override class func initialize()` and `dispatch_once` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution seems to be a singleton, provided in the Parse manual as follows, which works without any problems. This code works for all subclasses not only PFUser.  If done this way, there is no need to register the subclass in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
class User: PFUser, PFSubclassing {
    // MARK: PFUser Subclassing

    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }
    // non essential code removed
}
```